# VS2012 Object Browser shows members that I can't access

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, portable-class-library

Using the Object Browser in Visual Studio I'm trying to find a way to capture the default proxy settings for the host machine, in a portable library.

That's a long shot, I know. Not all platforms will have such a concept, so such an API probably doesn't exist in the portable library, however I can't understand why the Object Browser shows me the static property `WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy` because I can't use it in code, its not there.

[image: My Object Browser]

You can see I've limited the search to the .NET Portable Subset.

What am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you select an assembly in that list then you can see where it came from:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETPortable\v4.5

Which is the "home directory" for the PCL reference assemblies.  But that's not where the buck stops.  There are a large number of subdirectories in the Profile and v4.0\Profile directories that have directories with a name like "Profilexxx" where xxx is a number.  They contain substitute reference assemblies that contain the available classes in the specific set of targets you selected when you created the project.  In effect they'll *remove* classes that are not supported in one of the targets you selected.

The flaw in Object Browser is that it is not aware of those substitutes and doesn't know which specific profile you selected.  It only sees the reference assemblies in the home directory.  Presumably a //TODO somewhere in the VS source code.

Answer (score 2):

It is actually possible to hide class and structure members from IntelliSense. That doesn't mean it doesn't exist, IntelliSense just won't display it. I have seen a few BCL class members that don't show up in IntelliSense.

If you know it exists, you can just use it. You *shouldn't* get a red squiggly under said property or method (unless you're using it incorrectly).

Have a look at the [EditorBrowsableAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.editorbrowsableattribute.aspx) documentation. There's also a `BrowsableAttribute` that determines whether or not a property is displayed in a property grid for a control when using visual designers.

**UPDATE:** With the particular static property in question, what I wrote above is irrelevant. I performed a search like you did. The problem is that the `WebRequest` object doesn't live in System.dll for the portable libraries. Rather, this object resides in the `System.Net.Requests.dll` assembly. The namespace is still the same—`System.Net`. Try adding a reference to `System.Net.Requests.dll`.

When using the Object Browser and you perform a search, select the member that you're interested in. Then, click the button with the red 'X' on it next to the search bar. This will clear the search results list, but the member you selected previously will still be selected. Then, you'll be able to see where the member resides within the BCL (or, in your case, the Portable Class Libraries). When you perform these steps, you can see that the member lives in the `WebRequest` class in the `System.Net` namespace, but it's located in the `System.Net.Requests` assembly.

Comment: Regarding your first point, although interesting (personally, I knew about this attribute) you can choose to show hidden members in this tool. However it would explain this situation for some other members, so technically its accurate +1.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear to me whether it is causing your issue or not, but VS2012 Object Browser appears to have a bug which in some circumstances can cause it to display properties that do not actually exist. This can occur if you have a solution which has two projects, each of which has a reference to a different definition of the same fully-qualified class.

Example:

I am using a third-party library (DevExpress) for ASP grids.

In project A, I have DevExpress.Data.v9.1.Linq.dll which defines 
DevExpress.Data.Linq.LinqServerModeDataSourceSelectEventArgs with 2 public properties, QueryableSource and KeyExpression.

In project B, in the same solution I have DevExpress.Web.v11.2.dll which defines
DevExpress.Data.Linq.LinqServerModeDataSourceSelectEventArgs with 3 public properties, QueryableSource and KeyExpression, *and DefaultSorting*.

If I open a solution which contains both project A and B, and open the ObjectBrowser to inspect DevExpress.Data.v9.1.Linq.dll, it shows public property DefaultSorting is a member of this class (when really this property doesn't exist in v9.1 dll).  If you try to use this property in code, you will get a compiler error that the class " does not contain a definition for 'DefaultSorting'"

If I open a different solution which includes only project A *and not project B*, and open the ObjectBrowser to inspect that same v9.1 dll as above, it correctly shows the absence of the public property DefaultSorting.

---

If this is the cause of your issue above, then having both the .NET Portable Subset as well as wider .NET framework open and used in the same solution may be triggering this ObjectBrowser bug.
That could cause VS2012 show you properties that are only part of the full framework, even when you are using Object Browser to inspect the Portable Subset.